# Charging 4 protected li-ion batteries in series

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, lithium-ion, series

I have bougth 4 protectected li-ion batteries from e-bay ([these](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/4x-Protected-18650-3-7V-6000mAh-Li-ion-Rechargeable-Battery-For-Torch-Flashlight-/131324283630?ssPageName=ADME:X:eRTM:GB:1123)).

And I would like to know if I could charge them in series with 24V 0.5A charger ([this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/EU-Plug-AC-DC-24V-500mA-0-5A-Power-Supply-Cord-Adapter-5-5mm-x-2-1mm-/171761081697?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27fdc21d61)).

Since they are protected I conclude they can be charged with somewhat higher voltage, because they disconnect on 4.2V.

- Am I right?
- If not what would be the easiest solution to decrease cahrger's voltage on a proper level?

Comment: Anything without a decent data sheet is usually not worth bothering with. If you can link to the battery's data sheet (if you can find it), maybe you'll get answers.

Comment: 6000mAh LOL. Probably more like 1/5 of that.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, lol i realised that was a pretty stupid question, i tought that charging li-ions is simpler.. I know 6000mAh is bs bus I just wanted sth cheap..

Answer (score 2):

To charge a 18650 you need a current-limited supply which is also voltage-limited to 4.2 volts per cell. Thus, to charge 4 in series you would need a 16.8v supply. The cutoff voltage is quite critical and going beyond 4.3v/cell might even cause a fire hazard. 0.5A is acceptable provided this is the actual current limit and not the supply's max rating.

The other issue with charging in series is that if a faulty cell fails to charge, that may leave the other three to take a third of the supply voltage. Which would be a serious overcharge. Laptop packs usually have individual voltage monitoring to detect a failed cell situation and stop the charge.

I think you can see that (safe) lithium charging is not a simple matter, and whether a homebrew rig would be OK depends very much where and by whom it would be used.

The other point I would make is not to trust these Ebay adds. It may say protected, but do they actually have a charge limit board? The clue here is the 6000mAh, which is a blatant lie since no 18650 has that capacity - 4Ah is about the most you would find, and that will be expensive. If the seller is liar, how to you know he is telling you the truth on the safety aspect?

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

No, absolutely not, you'll ruin any lithium batteries simply by connecting a voltage source to it.  Lithium-Ion chemistry has at least a two-stage charge profile - first a 'constant current' stage, then once each cell reaches 4.2V, a 'constant-voltage' phase.  You MUST use a battery charger specifically intended for lithium batteries, otherwise you're just wasting money on batteries that will "mysteriously die" very quickly, and likely be blamed on some "cheap Chinese seller", when in fact the error is by the purchaser.

The "protection" is there to prevent over-voltage (during charge), under-voltage (during discharge), and over-current (either way).  But this does not regulate over-voltages, it just disconnects the battery from your abusive over-voltage supply.

There are websites dedicated to this stuff, including bargain-basement retailers like Hobbyking.

Answer (score 1):

I think in fact it should be possible to use a current limited power supply with a voltage higher than the series voltage. The voltage per cell then is determined by the charge state, as soon as 1 of the cells reach the protection voltage the whole series is disconnected... so it should work like a li-ion charger, first the cells are charged with cc and the charging is stopped when one cell reches the 4.3V. Of course if the cells are different not all the cells will be fully charged...